# When doing Partition Switching (SWITCH...TO) - why does the receiving partition need to be empty?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, partition

I'm monkeying around with `SWITCH...TO`, as a 'good practice' way to do a `TRUNCATE` & rebuild of a table.

```
INSERT INTO stg.MyTable SELECT * FROM CTE_Final

SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

*TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.MyTable*

ALTER TABLE stg.MyTable
SWITCH TO dbo.MyTable

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Per Microsoft, when doing partition switching, the destination partition must be empty.

[SQL Server 2008R2 - Transferring Data Efficiently by Using Partition Switching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191160(v=sql.105))

Why?

I'm conceptualizing this as what originally pointed to `stg.MyTable`, now points to `dbo.MyTable`, and vice versa. I'm thinking that's straight-up wrong, as I don't see why the 'switch' would require the 'destination' table to be empty. Or even why one table in particular is called *the* destination when they're both switching.

Comment: If you need to switch them around, you can create an empty staging table, switch a > staging, b > a, staging > b, then drop temp

Comment: If the new data didn't belong in an empty partition, how would you do it as a metadata operation? You'd need to combine the rows with the existing rows that would end up in the same partition. This means logging, dupe checking, index/stats updates, etc.

Comment: Also to Charlie's point I do it the other way as well, e.g. see [Refreshing SQL Server Tables With Less Interruption Using Partition Switching](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/09/sql-performance/refreshing-tables-partition-switching) ... and while Charlie isn't a fan I use a second staging table so the truncate itself is much less of a concern (scroll to the comments).

Comment: And to make your life easier, use a partitioned table as your staging table, instead of messing with a non-partitioned table on the correct filegroup with the correct check constraints.

Answer (score 3):

`SWITCH` is not a swap. The source partition is *moved* into the destination partition and the source partition becomes empty as a result. The empty target requirement ensures existing data is not inadvertently lost.

Answer (score 2):

No particular reason; it happened to be designed that way.  The paradigm case is rolling window partitioning, which only requires removing a partition from a table, not replacing it with another partition.